# Embedded video, Javascript button to make it fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, video

Is it possible to have a button on a page that makes an embedded video go to the fullscreen mode when clicked using Javascript?

Comment: This question is not relevant to embedded programming - the tag wiki explicitly says that the embedded tag does NOT apply to components embedded on a web page.

Comment: @Ian: retagged - now I am off to find the tag wiki ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is no actual code to go fullscreen. You can [enable the button](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html#fs) and you can [change the size](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_controls). Here is the demo http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html (from [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html))